# How to output different posts per page?

Tags: wp-query, query, pagination

I want to display one blog article less than on the following pages. The following code works but the the paginaton on the first page displays `1, 2, 3, 4` and on the next pages i get the correct pagination of `1, 2, 3` - What am i doing wrong?

```php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'trr_query_offset', 1 );
function trr_query_offset( &$query ) {
    if ( ! ( $query->is_home() || is_main_query() ) ) {
        return;
    }

    $offset = -1;

    $ppp = get_option( 'posts_per_page' );

    if ( $query->is_paged ) {
        $page_offset = $offset + ( ( $query->query_vars['paged']-1 ) * $ppp );
        $query->set( 'offset', $page_offset );
    } else {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', $offset + $ppp );
    }
}

add_filter( 'found_posts', 'trr_adjust_offset_pagination', 1, 2 );
function trr_adjust_offset_pagination( $found_posts, $query ) {
    $offset = -1;

    if ( $query->is_home() && is_main_query() ) {
        return $found_posts - $offset;
    }
    return $found_posts;
}
```

### Update

I'm using a custom Theme based on [Chisel](https://www.getchisel.co/) with Timber. This is my `home.twig`:

```html
[...]
<div class="tool-pagination">
    {% if posts.pagination.prev %}
      <a href="{{posts.pagination.prev.link}}" class="prev {{posts.pagination.prev.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Prev</a>
    {% endif %}
    <ul class="pages">
      {% for page in posts.pagination.pages %}
        <li>
          {% if page.link %}
            <a href="{{page.link}}" class="{{page.class}}">{{page.title}}</a>
          {% else %}
            <span class="{{page.class}}">{{page.title}}</span>
          {% endif %}
        </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% if posts.pagination.next %}
      <a href="{{posts.pagination.next.link}}" class="next {{posts.pagination.next.link|length ? '' : 'invisible'}}">Next</a>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
```

### Solution

I stumbled upon [a similar question here on stackexchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/124303/different-posts-per-page-setting-for-first-and-rest-of-the-paginated-pages?noredirect=1&lq=1) which helped with my problem: [Take a look at Case #2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/124426/79865) and especially the comment of **mach**

Comment: Are you using default theme? What is your pagination display template and logic? How's it design? It sounds like your template for pagination logic might have some flaw if the pagination is customised by it I guess.

Comment: @simongcc thanks for pointing that out, i have updated the Post!